# Use a snaphot version of the gradle dependency plugin (... in order to test gradle-3.0Mx)

Tags: spring, gradle, gradle-plugin

I stumbled over  compatibility issues related to the dependency plugin and gradle-3.0M1. Quickly, people told me this might be fixed in the trunk version of the plugin, but not in the latest release version 0.5.7.

Now I wanted to verify this but didn't find an easy way to use the snapshot version of the plugin. In the end, I

- downloaded the plugin source by cloning the git repo
- rebuilt the plugin
- copied the jar file into a folder
- made this folder available as flatDir within my build script

Is there a better way to do this? Is there a public mvn repo for the snapshots?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

Publish the plugin to your local maven repo (.m2) using either the older `maven` plugin or the newer `maven-publish` plugin.

In the project where you want to use/test the plugin you just build, add mavenLocal() as a repository in the `buildscript` section of build.gradle.